# Security enhancements in Oracle 12c R2 causing ORA-01031

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Our Application works fine till 12c R1 with below functionality.

User A: Application uses objects from Schema A

Role R : Role R have access to Objects on schema A

User B : Role R is granted to User B. So User B can access objects on  User A

This works fine till 12c R1.

But same functionality giving Error ORA-01031 Insufficient privileges error in App

Please let us know your thoughts on this.

Is there any parameter to turn off ONLY the security enhancements in 12c R2? Please suggest.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is caused by access to objects schema A?

Comment: Better to go through [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/managing-security-for-definers-rights-and-invokers-rights.html#GUID-EF625176-A3AA-47F5-BAEE-248DBAAF22A3) to know what could have went wrong with respect to invoker's right.